# Common point between IR and Vol option pricing models?

Tags: options, volatility, interest-rates, models

What is the common point between pricing models on options on Interest Rates and options on Volatility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common point is that both implied volatility and interest rates come with term structures.   This is exploited by H Buehler in [this paper](http://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-tuberlin/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/1318/file/buehler_hans.pdf) (and a few of his others).  In particular, in Equation 2.10 he defines a variance curve model $v$ as a martingale represented as

$$
dv_t(T) = \sum_{j=1}^d \beta^j_t(T) \, dW^j_t
$$

which is more or less the same as the HJM interest rate model.  He then goes on to derive when this can describe a variance curve and how to compute consistent functionals with it, namely that for a process $z$ one has to satisfy a variance-establishing equation like 3.1

$$
\partial_x G = \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_i \partial_{z_i} G +\frac12 \sum_{i,k=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^d \sigma_i^{(j)}  \sigma_k^{(j)}  \right) \partial_{z_i,z_k} G
$$

I really like all this machinery, though in practice I found it extremely difficult to implement for a volatility exotics trading system.